# How to implement a method for filtering goods with the specified options?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For example, the method takes as an argument an options object that contains parameters for searching {name: "item 2", price: "<= 1000", count: "> = 2"} each of the options is optional. The method must return a filtered array with the goods. filter By (options).**Required, the parameters from this object must be received through the destructuring.**

## I implemented this method this way, but it's wrong:

```js
    filterProductBy(dataset, filters, options) {
        this.options = options;
        let filtredFirst = dataset.map(x => {
            for (let subObjectName in x) {
                let inner = x[subObjectName];
                return inner;
            }
        });
        let filtred = [];
        for (let prop in filtres) {
            console.log(prop);
            let filtredInst = filtredFirst.filter(x => filters[prop](x[prop]));
            console.log(filtredInst);
            filtred = filtred.concat(filtredInst);
        }
        return filtred;
    }
console.log(shop.filterProductBy({
    name: "product",
    count: ">=10",
    price: ">=200"
}));
```

Tell me how to implement it correctly

### All my code

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
//Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor(products) {
        this.products = [];
    }

    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }
    filterProductBy(dataset, filters, options) {
        this.options = options;
        let filtredFirst = dataset.map(x => {
            for (let subObjectName in x) {
                let inner = x[subObjectName];
                return inner;
            }
        });
        let filtred = [];
        for (let prop in filtres) {
            console.log(prop);
            let filtredInst = filtredFirst.filter(x => filters[prop](x[prop]));
            console.log(filtredInst);
            filtred = filtred.concat(filtredInst);
        }
        return filtred;
    }
}

const shop = new Shop();
// create products
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 2", 1, 700));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 3", 2, 800));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 4", 3, 1000));
console.log(shop.filterProductBy({
    name: "product",
    count: ">=10",
    price: ">=200"
}));
```

Comment: What do mean by "It's wrong"?

Comment: Error: "TypeError: dataset.map is not a function"
And as I understand the wrong approach

Comment: You are calling the method `shop.filterProductBy` with an object. Objects don't have any method `map`. Map is an array method.

Comment: What should dataset be here? Surely it would always be the products which the shop has?

Comment: `shop.filterProductBy` expects three parameters but you are calling it with one. What are these three parameters? In the question text I read about one parameter `options`.

Comment: This method should show those products that we filter by options.

Comment: What are the parameters `dataset` and `filters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question this is the closest I can get. I'm guessing that `filterProductBy` should *only* take options, and that it should filter the products which the shop has.

It appears to do what you are asking, but currently only works with the filters >= and <=

```js
const getEvaluationFunction = filterString => filterString.indexOf('>=') > -1 ?
  (number, amount) => number >= amount :
  (number, amount) => number <= amount;


        //Product Creation Class
        class Product {
            constructor(name, count, price) {
                this.name = name;
                this.count = count;
                this.price = price;
            }
        }
        //Сlass where products are recorded
        class Shop {
            constructor(products) {
                this.products = [];
            }

            //method for adding a product
            addProduct(newProduct) {
                this.products.push(newProduct);
            }
            filterProductBy({name, price, count}) {
              return this.products
                .filter(product => name === undefined || product.name === name)
                .filter(product => price === undefined ||
                    getEvaluationFunction(price)(product.price, price.match(/(\d+)/)[0])
                 )
                 .filter(product => count === undefined ||
                    getEvaluationFunction(count)(product.count, count.match(/(\d+)/)[0])
                 )
            }
        }

        const shop = new Shop();
        // create products
        shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
        shop.addProduct(new Product("product 2", 1, 700));
        shop.addProduct(new Product("product 3", 2, 800));
        shop.addProduct(new Product("product 4", 3, 1000));
        console.log(shop.filterProductBy({
            price: ">=1000",
            count: ">=2",
        }));
```